# barplot of percentages per category, per variable

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Given the following example data:

```
df<-data.frame(cbind(cntry<- c("BE","ES","IN","GE","BE","ES","GE",NA,"IN","IN"),
gndr<- c(NA,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2),
plcvcrcR<-c(0,1,NA,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
plcpvcrR<-c(0,1,1,1,NA,0,0,0,0,0),
plccbrgR<- c(0,1,0,NA,0,1,0,1,1,0),
plcarcrR<-c(1,0,0,NA,1,0,1,0,0,0),
plcrspcR<-c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,NA)))
colnames(df)<- c("cntry", "gndr", "plcvcrcR", "plcpvcrR", "plccbrgR", "plcarcrR", "plcrspcR")
df
```

How could I make barplots showing for example for each gender (`gndr`) the percentage of `1-values` on the variables `plcpvcrR`, `plccbrgR`, `plcarcrR`? Prefeably the bars for each gender are grouped, and of a different colour for the different variables.

Something like this image, where one colour refers to the question, and the group to the gender (without the confidence interval):

https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSsAlUJsqdhxXHiY35FxFmVx3BREVji_ca24w9ub_OYEfZ3O50X5Q

I have experimented with the following function, of which I am aware it contains many flaws:

```
barplot(((colSums(df[c(3:5)], na.rm=TRUE)/nrow(df[c(3:5)]))*100)~gndr)
```

Comment: how do you want to deal with `NA`?

Comment: I would like to calculate it on the valid percent only (i.e. leave out `NA` from the total).

Comment: how about `NA` in gender? do you want to plot `1, 2 and NA`? And when you mean leave out NA from total, you mean when dividing by total, NA should NOT be included?

Comment: No, I want to plot 1 and 2, not NA for gender. And yes I meant, NA should NOT be included when dividing by the total.

Comment: okay great. I hope I've gotten it right. Take a look at the plot.

Comment: Yes, great! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
require(scales)
require(plyr)

# remove NA from gndr
df <- df[!is.na(df$gndr), ]
# now get percentages
df.o <- ddply(df, .(gndr), summarise, 
              plcpvcrR = sum(plcpvcrR == 1, na.rm = T)/sum(!is.na(plcpvcrR)), 
              plccbrgR = sum(plccbrgR == 1, na.rm = T)/sum(!is.na(plccbrgR)), 
              plcrspcR = sum(plcrspcR == 1, na.rm = T)/sum(!is.na(plcrspcR)))
# melt it:
df.m <- melt(df.o, id.var = "gndr")

# plot it:
ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x=gndr)) + geom_bar(aes(weights=value, fill=variable), 
      position = "dodge") + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

There may be easier/straightforward way to get percentages. Here's the plot:

[image]